# Why is size of H1 different inside a section element?

Tags: html, firefox, html-heading

I'm the very new beginner at HTML5 even in HTML. 
My confuse is about the heading which is used by HTML code, this is my code snippet:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Text A</h1> 
  </header>

  <section>
    <h1>Text B</h1>
    <article>
      <header>
        <hgroup>
          <h1>Text C</h1>
          <h2>Text C2</h2>
        </hgroup>
       </header>
```

Okay let's get to the topic, my question is;

1. the <h1> heading inside the <header> of the <body> part much bigger than <h1> inside the <section> part which is much bigger than <h1> inside the <article> of the <section> part. In other words : Text A > Text B > Text C, eventhough they're using the same heading.
2. why the Text C2 much bigger than Text C eventhough Text C2 using <h2> while Text C using <h1> and they are on the same location?

Is it some kind of bugs? I use the Firefox browser, by the way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [h1 tag smaller than h2, all insde a section tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642585/h1-tag-smaller-than-h2-all-insde-a-section-tag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/twmanha1/3/)

## It's just about the DOM structure.

because the different element has different default style to inherit. 
This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document) form MDN.

```
<h1>Text A</h1>

<header>
     <h1>Text A</h1> 
</header>
<section>
    <header>
         <h1>Text A</h1>

    </header>
</section>
<article>
    <header>
         <h1>Text A</h1>
          <section>
              <header>
                  <h1>Text A</h1>
              </header>
          </section>
    </header>
</article>
```

Comment: To add to Todd's answer, if you put `h1 {font-size: 2em;}` in your CSS, all your H1 will all be the same size.  You can style them differently using different selectors.  For example: `section header h1 {font-size: 3em;}` will style only the H1 that are inside HEADER that are inside SECTION.

Comment: @BobBrown By the way, all browsers have their self-style. if you use `h1{font-size:2em;}`. Actuallly, you use CSS to define the DOM. But in a pure html, The browser always render the DOM.

Comment: Okay, so I've open it on IE11, then the style is fine, for the Text A size = Text B size = Text C size (using <h1>), then Text C size > Text C2 size (as <h1> > <h2>), so it depends on our browser then. But this is difficult one, so how do we write our code so ALL of Browser interpret our code the same way, for this case in heading?

Comment: @Yagami: See my comment about CSS.

Comment: Okay I get it Bob, so the talk is about doing a extra code with CSS. For now I just skip that, but by the way I understand its point.

Comment: @ToddMark The MDN link you posted is interesting, but it doesn't answer the question of why two `h1` elements would have different sizes. In your answer, you show `h1` elements in different nesting locations, but you do not explain why that would cause the `h1`s to be different sizes. `section`, `article` etc. do not have any default `font-size` setting, so it cannot be that the `h1` inside `section` is inheriting something from it.

Comment: @ToddMark - Note that your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a header be the descendant of another header.

Comment: *By the way, all browsers have their self-style* The correct term would be "user agent stylesheet".

Answer (score 15):

Default rules for `h1` are different if it's inside a `section`. This is by design. See the following default Chrome "user agent" rule:

```
:-webkit-any(article,aside,nav,section) h1 { font-size: 1.5em; }
```

The above overrides the default Chrome rule for `h1`, which is

```
h1 { font-size: 2em; }
```

You can specify your own `h1` rule, which will override the above rule, since your own rules have a higher priority origin than user-agent rules:

```
h1 { font-size: 2em; }
```

This is not related to absolute vs. relative font sizes, nor inherited font sizes. It cannot be that the `h1` inside the `section` is smaller because it is inheriting from `section`, because `section` has no built-in font size.

The reason that `Text C2` is bigger than `Text C` is that the default rule mentioned above applies only to `h1` elements inside `article` elements, but not `h2`, for reasons best known to the browser developers. You could see this by examining the cascade in your favorite DOM/style inspector.

By the way, the `:-webkit-any` above is a Chrome-specific pseudo-class which matches any of the enclosed selectors, so it saves you from writing `article h1, aside h1, nav h1, section h1`. In FF, the equivalent would be `:-moz-any`. This is not standard, and in CSS4 will be implemented as a `:matches` pseudo-class.